# What should I have done to read these kind of input?

Tags: python

I am trying to recreate slippy.
My code won't stop printing the sequence  after giving the command to stop at the number where the number ends with "seq 10 15 | python3 slippy '/.1/q'"

My main objective is my code need to recognise q at the end of line and the number with it and should stop printing the sequence after that line number

For ex - seq 10 15 | python3 slippy '5q'" --> this means stop printing at 5th line.

Now I am trying to stop printing when the number from the sequence mathces any number which ends with 1

```
   Ex - seq 8 15 | python3 slippy '/.1/q'" -> means print the sequence until it reaches 11(as the numbers 2nd digit is 1)
```

q stands for quit the program when it reaches the target

```
import sys

slippy_commnad = sys.argv[1]

line_number = 0
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    line_number += 1
    if line == '':
        break
    print(line, end = '')
    if slippy_commnad[-1] == 'q':
        address = int(slippy_commnad[0:-1])
        # print(address)
        if line_number == address:
            break
```

Comment: What's "slippy"?

Comment: [S]ed [L]anguage [I]nterpreter in [P]ure [PY]thon.

Comment: `slippy_commnad[0:-1]` is `/.1/`. That can't be parsed as an integer, so what are you expecting `address` to be? You should be getting an error from `int()`, not repeated output.

Comment: In fact this code doesn't even run for me.  `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '/.1/'`

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env python3.   Add this at the begging of the ode to run it

Comment: My main objective is my code need to recognise q at the end of line and the number with it and should stop printing the sequence after that line number

For ex - seq 10 15 | python3 slippy '5q'" --> this means stop printing at 5th line.

Now I am trying to stop printing when the number from the sequence mathces any number which ends with 1

   Ex - seq 8 15 | python3 slippy '/.1/q'" -> means print the sequence until it reaches 11(as the numbers 2nd digit is 1)

Comment: Like @Barmar pointed out, the code you have shared would not run. `.1/` from `slippy_commnad[0:-1]` cannot be parsed into an int

Comment: You need to parse that and recognize that `/.../` is a regular expression. Extract the regexp from between the `//` and use `re.search()` to match it.

Comment: @Barmar. So I should the change address line and use re.search for it to recognise it ?

Comment: You should write a parser. Addresses can be used with any command. So you need to split the argument into address and command. The address can be a number or a regular expression, or a range of addresses. This is called modularity.